# Windows version of Mac OS X's display key press widget equivalent?

Tags: windows, macos

I'm not an expert at OS X at all, but I saw a screencast one time where the user was on OS X and it showed the keys he was pressing in a little window in the corner.  Does an equivalent app exist for Windows that will display key presses in little window for screencasting?  A free version if exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [KeyPosé - Flavour your Screencasts with Shortcuts](http://katastrophos.net/magnus/blog/2008/08/01/keypose-flavour-your-screencasts-with-shortcuts/). It is exactly what you are after:

> How often have you found yourself recording a screencast annoyed by the fact that only the mouse is visible? I haven’t seen any screen recording software that provided an easy way to display shortcuts on screen as you type.
>
> Most of the fancy UI stuff happens in OS X land (see [Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/overview/) ) but I needed the functionality under Windows.
>
> So on a chilly afternoon I sat down and wrote a litte utility that implements a global key logger which diplays all shortcuts and keystrokes as you type - on screen and with a semi-transparent overlay. This makes it very easy to show any shortcuts you use if you for example record a software demo.
>
> **To get a feeling what it looks like: [Screencast](http://katastrophos.net/magnus/blog/keypose/keypose.html)**

Answer (score 1):

On OSX The screen recording sofware displays the key on the recorded video. Some version of iShowU does (pro+ whatever, only the high end). This is not a separate program that just displays the key pressed on screen but rather part of the screen capture program.

I was actually looking for such aprogram that displays the keys pressed on screen so that I can have this feature with the lower version of iShowU I purchased :-) And got here...